# Bootstrap Check Box Binding With Knockout Freezed

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Bootstrap http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0135486

I have Binded a Observable Array of Values to Check Box But here the CheckBox have been Freeze as Disabled but I cannot check the check box.

```
<div class="box-content" data-bind="foreach: AvailableWorkingDayList">
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">
      <ul class="box-list">
        <li>
          <i class="icon-calendar"></i><span> <label data-bind="text: WorkingDay,attr:{for:WorkingDayValue}" class="control-label col-lg-3"></label></span>
          <span class="pull-right"><input class="iButton-icons-tab" type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:WorkingDayValue,attr:{'id':WorkingDayId}"/></span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is Where I fill the Object

```
$.each(tmpList, function (j, value) {
        utCmnBusinessCalendarViewModel.AvailableWorkingDayList.push(new NonWorkingDayObj(
            value.WorkingDayId,
            value.WorkingDay,
            '1'
            ));
    });
```

This is my ObjectDefinition

```
var NonWorkingDayObj = function (workingDayId, workingDay, workingDayValue) {
        var self = this;
        self.WorkingDayId = ko.observable(workingDayId);
        self.WorkingDay = ko.observable(workingDay);
        self.WorkingDayValue = ko.observable(workingDayValue);
        return true;
    };
```

Comment: you're binding your checkbox to a non-boolean value. I'm pretty sure workingDayValue has to be true/false, not 1/something else

Comment: i tried that also but not working

Comment: This is the Problem Occur When the use of forEach Binding. Single Check Box are Working

Answer (score 0):

If something is disabling checkboxes, it's not in the code you included. This works fine. Is it possible you have some element (another div, for example) overlaying the checkboxes so that they can't be clicked?

```js
function newEntry(id, name, value) {
  return {
    WorkingDayId: ko.observable(id),
    WorkingDay: ko.observable(name),
    WorkingDayValue: ko.observable(value)
  };
}
vm = {
  AvailableWorkingDayList: ko.observableArray([
    newEntry('DayId1', 'DayName1', '1'),
    newEntry('DayId2', 'DayName2', '2'),
    newEntry('DayId3', 'DayName3', '3')
  ])
};
vm.CheckedDays = ko.computed(function() {
  return ko.utils.arrayFilter(vm.AvailableWorkingDayList(), function(item) {
    return item.WorkingDayValue();
  });
});
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="box-content" data-bind="foreach: AvailableWorkingDayList">
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">
      <ul class="box-list">
        <li>
          <i class="icon-calendar"></i><span> <label data-bind="text: WorkingDay,attr:{for:WorkingDayValue}" class="control-label col-lg-3"></label></span>
          <span class="pull-right"><input class="iButton-icons-tab" type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:WorkingDayValue,attr:{'id':WorkingDayId}"/></span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<h2>Checked</h2>
<ul data-bind="foreach: CheckedDays">
  <li data-bind="text: WorkingDay"></li>
</ul>
```